# CSS selector nightmare

Tags: css, jquery-plugins

I've been building a simple menu with a jQuery plugin called Superfish. I'm almost there with it except for that one last really annoying thing. I added a class so that sub-menus can drop down to the right instead of the left and I've added a new arrow sprite for right-pointing arrows. It behaves as I want it with one exception. Here's the link: http://richswebarchive.com/terrificart/home/rico_index.php

If you hover on 'Artwork' and then on 'Choose By Both' and move into a further sub-menu the arrow in the 'Choose by Both' box turns back to the left. The behaviour in further sub-menus is correct, the problem is just at this first level. I've tried fiddling with the css loads but I can't seem to fix it.

If anyone could help me out with this I'd be most grateful. Thanks.

Comment: The problem occurs in Chrome, but not Firefox for me.

Comment: That's weird, because I do see the problem here. (Firefox 3.6.13, OSX)

Comment: Weird, when I inspect it with Firebug the error stops, but otherwise is present in FF. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You're resetting the background image somewhere in a third level LI (or UL). Check your CSS for any place the right-pointed image is called and create a new selector overwriting the arrow with an arrow pointing to the left.

The parent element (to write the selector) is .leftdrop.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer Damien and please forgive my ignorance but I don't understand it. I'm trying to get rid of a left-pointing arrow, so why would I want to add in new selectors for left-arrows? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In this code block at line 158 in the Suprfish CSS:

```
/* apply hovers to modern browsers */
.sf-menu ul a:focus > .sf-sub-indicator,
.sf-menu ul a:hover > .sf-sub-indicator,
.sf-menu ul a:active > .sf-sub-indicator,
.sf-menu ul li:hover > a > .sf-sub-indicator,
.sf-menu ul li.sfHover > a > .sf-sub-indicator {
    background-position: -10px 0; /* arrow hovers for modern browsers*/
}
```

Change the background position to `backgroind-position: -10px 100px;` This might fix the issue. I haven't been able to test it, but see if that helps.

Comment: That's the block that puts the arrow back to the left, but changing that value to 100 takes you outside the sprite graphic and nothing shows up on hover. It's a really weird problem, removing the last two selectors in the block has some strange effects, but I don't understand why.

Comment: Sorry, try MINUS 100px `-100px;`

Comment: That puts in the downward arrow on all hovers. It's something to do with this first level sub-menu but I just can't work out what.